# Error al importar registros de Excel a SQL

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2008

Estoy importando registros de *Excel* a *SQL* con *openrowset* en un procedimiento almacenado, **cuando importo menos de 30,000 registros funciona sin problema**, pero con más me arroja el mensaje de error :

> El proveedor OLE DB "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" del servidor vinculado
>   "(null)" devolvió el mensaje "Unexpected error from external database
>   driver (1).". Mens. 7311, Nivel 16, Estado 2, Línea 1 No se puede
>   obtener el conjunto de filas de esquema "DBSCHEMA_COLUMNS" para el
>   proveedor OLE DB "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" del servidor vinculado
>   "(null)".
>   El proveedor admite la interfaz, pero devuelve un código de error cuando se usa.

Estoy usando *SQL 2008 R2* en Windows Server 2012 el código es el siguiente:

SQL

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
   'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\CargaDatos\Prueba2.xlsx', [Hoja1$])
```

Comment: Puede ser algo de los datos!. Yo probaria separando los datos en dos archivos (o incluso mas) por ejemplo cada 10mil registros. Para ver si es eso. Tambien podrias probar exportando el excel a CSV y realizando la misma accion con otro proveedor al momento de importar.

Comment: Ya he realizado esa prueba antes y no es un problema con los datos, el CSV lo puedo importar con un BULK INSERT, pero necesito que sea directamente de Excel.

Comment: Creo que es un problema de la cadena de conexión. Has intentado usar `Excel 12.0 Xml;...`?

Comment: Modifiqué la cadena de conexión y lo mismo, con pocos registros trabaja sin problema, pero con muchos me sigue mandando el mismo error.

Comment: ¿Podría ser un problema con alguno de los campos? Quiero decir, ahora mismo te estás trayendo todos los campos. Prueba a traer solamente 1 campo concreto, a ver si te sigue dando problemas al volcar más de 30.000 registros. Si no te falla, podría ser que el problema esté en un campo en concreto, ¿no?